python - How to get Unicode characters to display as boxes instead of accented letters - "x96\x88" and "x96\x80"
I have a table that is returning the characters "â\x96\x88" and "â\x96\x80"
These are displaying as "â" and "â"
However, what I need is for them to display as "█" and "▀".
How do I handle this in Python so they display as I wish?
This is in macOS using python 3, both in the terminal console, and also within jupyter-notebook.
I am scraping the table with these values from a web page with pandas.read_html (I can't share the page unfortunately) where they display as the boxes, but then within the dataframe and thereafter in python they are â.

Displaying these characters where? In a terminal (if so, on which platform)? In a file? In a webpage? A GUI? Using which text encoding?

It's the same both in python 3 on macOS terminal, and python 3 in jupyter notebook on macOS. On the web page I scrape the table from they are boxes, but when I scrape those into a dataframe, and thereafter within python, they display as an accented "â"

It is an encoding issue. The characters are unicode and I wasn't specifying the encoding during table scraping in read_html.
I added ", encoding='utf-8'" to my read_html parameters.
df_list = pd.read_html(URL, header=0, encoding='utf-8')

Previously it was:
df_list = pd.read_html(URL, header=0)


You don't show the code read_html or the context anywhere in the original post. I feel like had you done that you'd maybe noted, and others may have pointed out, this is already well covered here and should have been closed as a duplication. One of the points of SO is to have few questions posts covering topics with highly scoring answers scoring high. Creating new posts of the same questions and answers without reference to the originals doesn't do that. Not looking too hard, I see here and here.

Thank you Wayne - lack of code should not have happened. BUT it is not a duplicate because I was looking at an entirely separate section of the code and would not have posted the read_html. If I had realised it was an issue at the read_html stage I wouldn't have needed to ask the question because I already had the solution. People are too quick to assume these posts are duplicates, when the question is coming from the opposite end of the issue to the "duplicates" referenced. We're all learning here, and this is new to me. And I answered my own question fairly quickly with my own research.
